# Netty - how to get all client channel?

Tags: java, networking, netty

I was using netty example codes - telnet packet, Now the code can establish server and client to chat using telnet, but client can only talk to server. I am rewriting it to make the clients can talk to all the clients, so I need to keep a channel list, so when a client is contact the server, the server can send the message to all of the clients.
Can anyone tell me how could I get all clients channel?
(The example code is [enter link description here](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/telnet))

Comment: did you manage to get all client channels correctly?

Answer (score 15):

**For Netty 4.0.X**

In main Class you need to declare the ChannelGroup object:

```
 final ChannelGroup channels = 
                new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);
```

When a new client is connected (you should pass the channels object in the constructor to you handler class):

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    channels.add(ctx.channel());
}
```

To get all clients, just iterate the channels object:

```
for (Channel ch : channels) {
    //do something with ch object
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

Mauricio's proposal is a good one. In addition, the Netty API already provides a channel container in the [ChannelGroup](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html). It is thread safe and also provides several additional features such as group operations on all contained channels and automatic removal of contained channels when they are closed. From the javadoc:

> A thread-safe Set that contains open Channels and provides various
>   bulk operations on them. Using ChannelGroup, you can categorize
>   Channels into a meaningful group (e.g. on a per-service or per-state
>   basis.) A closed Channel is automatically removed from the collection,
>   so that you don't need to worry about the life cycle of the added
>   Channel. A Channel can belong to more than one ChannelGroup.

Answer (score 3):

here's a little example (overrides channelConnected of SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler):

```
ChannelGroup allConnected = new DefaultChannelGroup("all-connected");

@Override
public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
    super.channelConnected(ctx, e);
    allConnected.add(e.getChannel());
}
```

you can now send messages to all connected channels like so:

```
    ChannelBuffer cb = ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer("hello".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    allConnected.write(cb);
```

Comment: For Netty 4/5, there's a similar example in the javadoc, http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html which overrides channelActive() instead and also calls the super-method _after_ adding the channel.

Comment: @StefanL given the example in the documentation, how can I obtain the channel of the client?? (in the example: channelA, channelB..)

Answer (score 1):

At the **[channelConnected](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/telnet/TelnetServerHandler.java#L50)** event, grab the client from the **ChannelHandlerContext** and store it somewhere (a concurrent collection would be nice, like **[ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)**). You will also have to implement the **[channelClosed](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.html#channelClosed%28org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext,%20org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelStateEvent%29)** method to remove the disconnected channel from your collection.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it at first, but failed since I don't know that the implementation ChannelPipelineFactory generate the Handler, by construct a storage for the channels in the right position, I have success to do it. Anyway, thanks a lot:)